# Magento 2 : Use of echo language construct is discouraged

Tags: magento2, controllers, coding-standards

i had develop magento 2 extension 
and i have use ajax call to my controller for getting some data.
but coding standard provide me some error

[image: Use of echo language construct is discouraged.]

my controller code is ......

```
public function execute()
{  
    echo $mediaUrl.'cs/test/'.$file.$extension;   
}
```

i had use this code for js

```
function getFileUrl() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php  echo $block->getUrl('modulename/index/index'); ?>",
        data:{itemId:jQuery('input[name=item]').val(),data:jQuery('#file').html() }
    }).done(function(data) {
        jQuery('#file').val(data);
    });
}
```

if have any solution pleas provide it.

Comment: Reference => https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-jquery-ajax-request/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $response */
    $response = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
    $response->setContents('your string here');
    return $response;
```

or you can try with json

```
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $response */
    $response = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $response->setData(['success' => true, 'url' => 'your url here']);
    return $response;
```

But then you have to change your js that handles the ajax response and get the url from `response.url`.

Comment: how to use response.url in js

Comment: in your case `data.url`

Comment: ohh i mean that i need to define some thing in require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui','response'] ! 

Answer (score 0):

Your execute function expects a return, so you just need to change the **echo** to **return**

```
public function execute()
{  
    $url = $mediaUrl.'cs/test/'.$file.$extension;
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: return is not working i had try id also but out response is null

Comment: try to store in a variable first before passing to return